# Modify the title and the description of a link - Google+ share API on Android

Tags: android, google-plus

I am implementing [Google+ Share](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/share/) and I was wondering if it's possible to modify the title or the description of a given link. That's because I want to share a result and I want my message to not be able to get modified by the user. My current Code:

```
Button googleShareBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.googleShareBtn);
        googleShareBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                // Launch the Google+ share dialog with attribution to your app.
                Intent shareIntent = new PlusShare.Builder(MyActivity.this)
                        .setType("text/plain")
                        .setText("Your results: "+result)
                        .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://www.google.com"))
                        .getIntent();
                startActivityForResult(shareIntent, 0);
            }
        });
```

Here the user can change the passed message from `setText()`. Keep in mind that in Facebook 4 API I can use [setContentDescription()](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/ShareLinkContent.Builder), so I am looking for something similar in Google+ API.

Comment: you are creating what it seems like an implicit intent and or an explicit intent where the external activity *allows* the user to edit these fields. Either way what you're saying is not possible. You will have to find an alternative api (which probably doesn't exist, due to the open [non spam] nature of Android)

Comment: However the facebook API supports the exact same thing, I am not asking for something programmaticaly imposible, but I agree on the fact that google+ API might not support this feature on the current version.